# multiprocessing imap suprress child process print

Tags: python, multiprocessing

While I'm running the following code in Jupyter notebook (python3.5):

```
def process(doc):
    print('Process Hey!')
with Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.imap(process, docs)
```

This would not give the print to the notebook, but if I try using pool.map instead, it will spit out the words. So I'm really curious what's going on up here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs [imap](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) `A lazier version of map()`, `imap` returns an iterator `map` returns a list:

```
In [24]:  with Pool() as pool:
            results = pool.map(process, docs)
            print(type(results))
   ....:     
Process Hey!
Process Hey!
<class 'list'>


In [25]:  with Pool() as pool:
                results = pool.imap(process, docs)
                print(type(results))
   ....:     
<class 'multiprocessing.pool.IMapIterator'>

In [27]:  with Pool() as pool:
                results = pool.imap(process, docs)
                for _ in results:
                     pass
   ....:     
Process Hey!
Process Hey!
In [28]:  with Pool() as pool:
            results = pool.imap(process, docs)
            list(results)
 ....:     
Process Hey!
Process Hey!
```

It is equivalent to the difference between `itertools.imap` and `map` in python2 i.e lazily evaluated vs greedily evaluated:

```
In [3]: from itertools import imap

In [4]: r = imap(lambda x: x+1, [1,2,3])
In [4]: r
Out[5]: <itertools.imap at 0x7f09170f1e10>
In [6]: list(r)
Out[6]: [2, 3, 4]

In [7]: r = map(lambda x: x+1, [1,2,3])    
In [8]: r
Out[8]: [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I see, so unless you do something else later with the iterator it would not actually compute the function called by imap. Thanks!